# Issue with updating NuGet packages (VS2017)

Tags: visual-studio-2017, nuget

Visual Studio 2017 - Saying "Package restore failed" while updating the NuGet packages as following:

[image]

Comment: You need to provide more information about what you did, then you got this error, for example, when you update xxx package, you get the error xxx. And you can open the output window, there should be more specific error messages there.

Comment: All packages displays this message seperately.

Answer (score 1):

> Issue with updating NuGet packages (VS2017)

To resolve this issue, first, you should make sure your `Target Framework` that is used to compile your android application, **Use Latest Platform (Android 8.1 (Oreo))**.

Check source: [Understanding Android API Levels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/android-api-levels?tabs=vswin)

Second, if you confirm your `Target Framework` is `Android 8.1 (Oreo)`, then **Select all packages** checkbox, and click **Update** button:

[image]

After that, all nuget packages can be updated to latest version.

The reason for this issue:

To find the reason for this issue, change the MSBuild build log to Detailed, `Tools`->`Options`->`Projects and Solutions`->`Build and Run`->`MSBuild project build output verbosity`:**Detailed**.

When you update one of those default nuget packages, in the output you will get following dependencies conflict errors:

> NU1107: Version conflict detected for Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat.
>   Reference the package directly from the project to resolve this issue.
>   App1.Android -> Xamarin.Android.Support.Design 27.0.2 ->
>   c (= 27.0.2)   App1.Android ->
>   Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat 25.4.0.2 ->
>   Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat (= 25.4.0.2).

That means when you update the default package `Xamarin.Android.Support.Design` to 27.0.2, one of its dependencies, `Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat` also need to be updated to 27.0.2. **However**, other nuget package `Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat 25.4.0.2` still reference the `Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat` with the old version 25.4.0.2. So you will get that error.

**To resolve this error, you should update all default package at once instead of one of them.**